# Cannot find "\appcompat_v7_4\bin\appcompat_v7_4.jar'

Tags: java, android, android-listview, jar

After a certain time in android SDK i could not find the specific "appcompat_v7_4.jar" file and hence i could not run the application, even after copying "appcompat_v7_2.jar" and renaming as "_v7_2.jar" the error say -> Cannot find "\appcompat_v7_4\bin\appcompat_v7_4.jar' /and warning as/ "cannot write catch".

What else to do to correct this error.

Comment: its a library project and you should reference the same. Check this https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html